# how to fix: website pages show question marks in online but not in localhost

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, iis, character-encoding

i have website and some letters shows like � that but only in online and not in localhost, the site is in asp.net-MVC, i used meta charset="utf-8", but it doesn't help

Comment: Compare settings between localhost and live. Such as PHP version, apache version etc. Im pretty sure there are differences between both. It's a common issue!

Comment: Hi - I've had a similar problem in the past. I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio (note for the future - give as much detail as possible in your question). When you save the file (File/Save [your view] As) select the arrow next to the save button and choose 'save with encoding'. In the pop up window you can then select UTF-8. My specific setting is `Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001`. 
If your content is stored in a database or other non-view place you will need to give us some more info.

Comment: I use visual studio 2017 and  meta charset="utf-8" in _layout.cshtml, content is stored in database and when i started localhost content shows normally but in online some letters shows like � that